# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218 laravel 5.2 on update data

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

Please help me, im newbie in laravel and get an error 
when I will update data field from button, like this

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

and im using **Routes**:

```
Route::post('/verify', 'DataPelamarController@verify');
```

and I write my **Controller** like bellow:

```
public function verify(Request $request, $id){
    DB::table('databeasiswas')->update([
        'status_pendaftaran'=>'1']);
    return redirect(url('pendaftar'));
}
```

and this is my **view**

```
<a href ="{{ url('verify') }}" name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH" >
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-vk btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Verify Data</button>
</a>
```

thanks before..

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line. Patch is for updating, Post for new db entries. This is just a convention. You can use post for both.

```
Route::patch('/verify', 'DataPelamarController@verify');
```